# SortableJS - Disable sort on a condition

Tags: sortablejs

I am using sortable.js to make sortable lists.

I want to disable sorting when a condition is met.

How can id do this?

Here is what i have tried;

```
var sortableRequest = Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortRequest'), { animation: 150, sort: true, group: "sorting" });
if (stringvar == "stopsorting"){
    sortableRequest = Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortRequest'), { animation: 150, sort: false, group: { name: 'sorting', put: false});
}
```